# Trouble with tables

Tags: html, css

HTML / CSS noobie here.

Sorry if this is a very easy problem, but I don't know how to word it on Google.

[image: Website]

This is a (very, very) rudimentary website I am making for my high school robotics team.

How do I get the sidebar to start at the top and not centered? It is a table inside of another table.

Here is the CSS for the "sidebar:"

```
#sidebar {
height: 100%;
width: 200px;
}
```

EDIT: Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
<table>
    <tr class="banner">
        <h1>Banner goes here</h1>
        <p>Nothing here is final. No, the final site will not be this ugly.</p>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="center" id="sidebar">
                <tr><td>Home</td></tr>
                <tr><td>About</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Sponsors</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Contact Us</td></tr>
                <tr><td>FTC 5969</td></tr>
                <tr><td>FRC 4538</td></tr>
                <tr><td>FTC 7084</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Media</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Events</td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            (main content)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show your html as well?

Comment: I'm sure some more comments will come in, but let me just throw out some ideas. If you're not sure of an element's position, add a border or give it a background color. Also, play at jsfiddle.net and you can experiment with lots of different stuff. Also, try not to use tables for layout, switch over to divs. It's a bit frustrating at first, but once you get the hang of it, it'll work.

Comment: @TimSPQR: I switched to a div layout, and it's working better and easier than having tons of <tr> and <td> tags! Thanks! I'm also very surprised with the speed of solutions; if I have any more questions I'll come here first! You guys rock!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've figured this out for you.

I tried this with the exact same thing on my site

```
<td style="vertical-align:top;">
```

Add that style attribute to the td tag surrounding your content on the left and it should whack it up to the top of the cell it's in.

The CSS alternative is this

```
#sidebar {
height: 100%;
width: 200px;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

or if you specifically want it just for your td tags just do

```
#sidebar td {
vertical-align:top;
}
```

underneath your main #sidebar entry

Comment: This answer is valid. But i would always recommend to use the class instead of the id: `table.center td` or `.center td`. This way you have a general css-rule for every table-cell which is a good starting point to ensure a consistent style throughout all pages.

Comment: Yeah that's true, but an id is generally for single use, such as a navigation bar which is singular and doesn't need to be repeated on the same document multiple times

Comment: plus I was just adding to the code he has already made as to not cause confusion

Answer (score 2):

If you use table inside of other table just use **vertical-align:top** on TD of #sidebar.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/nukec/7XjTv/

HTML:

```
<table class="one" >
    <tr>
        <td>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>            sdsdsdsdsd
                   </td>
    </tr>
</table> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table{
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.one{
    height:500px;
}
td{
    vertical-align:top;
}
```